# php artisan commands not taking effect

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

Not a single command working when I type **php artisan "command"**.

```
Last login: Mon Feb 16 20:17:50 on ttys000
Pro:~ nzrv$ cd ~/Sites/t
Pro:t nzrv$ php artisan --version
Pro:t nzrv$ php artisan make:controller PagesController
Pro:t nzrv$ php artisan
Pro:t nzrv$
```

Log files are empty, nothing related to artisan.

Problem not present on a newly installed apps. Output when I run composer update command:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error
[RuntimeException]
Error Output:

update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

It seems composer can't run clear-compiled because of not working artisan and I don't know where to look.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get a more descriptive error when running `php artisan clear-compiled` on its own?

Comment: it's completely ignoring me

Comment: Does `php artisan --version` work?

Comment: nope, nothing works. Just thinks about one second and thats it.

Comment: But the framework itself works?

Comment: all working but artisan, Laravel 5.0.5

Comment: What do the Laravel Logs say? On v5 the logs are in: the folder: `storage/logs/`. Files are usually called `laravel-DATE.log`

Comment: nothing related to artisan, when I clear it and try any commands nothing shows up.

Comment: Hmm. You could try downloading the latest `artisan` file from [github](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/artisan)

Comment: Tried it already. Contents of the files are identical. after $status = $kernel->handle(
 $input = new Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput,
 new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput
); nothing executing.

Comment: Is your `storage` folder writable? `777` recursively to be sure...

Comment: chmod -R 777 ~/Sites/t/storage, not helped, not the case I guess

Comment: I suspect it's something with the boilerplate part of the application. (Everything in the `laravel/laravel` repository). The easiest way to fix this is probably to make a new installation and copy the application files over...

Comment: Tried it, it seems something in my app folder causing this, but cant get what exactly

Comment: or just a broken component

Comment: Weird. Good luck figuring it out... ;)

Comment: Sounds more like a problem with running PHP in CLI. Does your PHP work in CLI? Try for example `php -v`, any output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with config file.
I've installed breadcrumbs package and it's config was causing it.

```
return array(
    'separator' => '&nbsp;<img src="'.asset('img/breadcrumbsDivider.gif').'">&nbsp;',
    'view'  => 'frontend/breadcrumbs',
    'min_depth' => 2,
    'last_linkable' => false
);
```

I've changed it with following code and it started working.

```
return array(
    'separator' => '&nbsp;<img src="/img/breadcrumbsDivider.gif">&nbsp;',
    'view'  => 'frontend/breadcrumbs',
    'min_depth' => 2,
    'last_linkable' => false
);
```

There is was not difference to my application but not for artisan.

Comment: which config file exactly?can you elaborate. Facing the same issue,artisan works in other projects but not in one of them.no response at all.How to figure out what might be blocking it?

Answer (score 1):

Today I have faced this issue when running artisan command. While searching what is the problem to not let artisan command to be executed saw that for test purpose only written `exit()` exist in my routes folder in web.php file. And after disabling `exit()` everything worked as waited. I think that is weird issue but this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't do comments. So, take care this things:

- Are you executing the commands in the laravel folder?
- How you tried executing `composer install` again?
- Are updating from a old version of Laravel? http://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade